# How do I tell Typescript to never use absolute paths except for node_modules?

Tags: typescript

Is there, like, a way to force Typescript to only ever use relative imports for project-local files? That's it.. That's the whole question...

Comment: To use relative imports... where? In the emitted code?

Comment: Apologies, when suggesting imports using IntelliSense.

Comment: This will almost certainly depend on the IDE. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this in VS Code with:

```json
{ 
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
}
```